# How to Implement flyway-play Java Migration

Tags: java, database, migration, flyway

Is it possible to use Java migration script in flyway-play (3.0.0)?

SQL migrations work fine but when I place the example Java migration script into either app\db\migration\V1_0_1__PopulateDatabase.java or into the same directory as the SQL script, it is not being recognised as a valid migration script.

Anyone tried this before?

Comment: have you managed to get it to work? I have the same need

Comment: In the end I stopped using flyway-play and went back to just using flyway-core in a separate sub-project.  Although this supports Java and Scala migration scripts, it wasn't my main reason for dropping flyway-play.  With flyway-play, the project needs to compile and being in early development, along with generating the schema from the database, it just got too messy.  Having a separate project made things much more flexible, with the added advantage of supporting Java/Scala scripts.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [flyway-play README](https://github.com/flyway/flyway-play#place-migration-scripts), Flyway migrations (scripts or Java migrations) need to be placed on the classpath at `db/migration/${dbName}`.

For example, imagine I have a database connection called `default` specified in `application.conf` like so:

```
db.default {
  driver=org.postgresql.Driver
  url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/database"
}
```

In this case, I need to place sql migrations at `conf/db/migration/default` and Java migrations at `app/db/migration/default`.

In your case, you haven't included a database name in the Java migration's path. Whereas you've put the migration at `app/db/migration/V1_0_1__PopulateDatabase.java`, it should probably somewhere like `app/db/migration/default/V1_0_1__PopulateDatabase.java`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write your migrations in Scala and flyway-play will pick them up (it scans for both Scala and Java migrations). The flyway-play repo has an example Play app which does this: https://github.com/flyway/flyway-play/tree/master/playapp/app/db/migration/java